# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '@'

Tags: php

Not sure what I need to do in this situation as I have tried a few ways to fix this.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)^/" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email ))
{
    $response="You entered an invalid e-mail.";
    $form_success   = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: What is `^/` supposed to do? And the `@` and more regex after it? I think you need to learn regular expressions...

Comment: @orftz - whilst it's not full edit privileges, can I remind you that you too can edit posts: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/ In addition you can earn up to 1000 rep by submitting valid edits. This feature makes asking users to edit their posts somewhat redundant now. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev, you're right. Plus, commenting is usually as stretching as editing. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

PHP treats `"/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)^/"` as the whole expression (`/` is treated as [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)). Anything after that will be treated as modifier. [`@` is not a valid modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Maybe you want to escape the last slash `\/` but you are then missing one at the end `$/`. Why do you use string concatenation here? The whole regex does not seem to match email addresses.

Anyway, [learn regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) [before you use them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php). In this case it is better to use PHP's [**`filter_var`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This (email_a) email address is considered valid.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That regular expression is pretty messed up.  Use this instead:

```
/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/
```

Did you write that expression yourself?  I suggest you read up on regex here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

The reason your regex isn't working is because you're expecting the concatenation of strings to do something, which it doesn't.  The string you had equates to this:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)^/@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

There are multiple problems with this.

1. There are several (unescaped) forward slashes (`/`) in the string
2. There is no forward slash at the end of the string
3. I'm not sure if this would actually match an email, I'd have to test it.

The error you get is because it thinks the second unescaped forward slash marks the end of the expression.  So...

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)^/
```

Is what it has.  Everything after that is treated as a modifier (e.x. `i` for case-insensitivity).  `@` is not a valid modifier.

Answer (score 0):

A 'modifier' in regex is a character that appears outside the main expression. There are a handful of allowed modifiers, which perform a variety of actions. For example, the 'i' modifier makes the expression case insensitive. '@' is not a valid modifier.

So why are you getting told this?

You have a `/` character in your expression, which is being treated as the end of your expression, because it matches the `/` at the beginning of the expression. Therefore everything after the `/` is being treated as a modifier character because it is outside the expression.

The first character after the `/` is a `@`, so that is what is being warned about.

As for what that `/` is doing there, I can't really tell -- it doesn't look like it's meant to be there, and neither the `^` in front of it.

My suggestion is to remove the `^/`, and put a `$/` at the end of the expression.

Having said that, it looks like you're trying to validate and email address. If that's the case, I'd suggest looking up some valid expressions, because this one looks like it could do with a lot of work (more than just the changes I've already suggested).

Hope that helps.